# @Rollback @Transactional is not working in acceptance test

Tags: java, jpa, transactions, junit5, rollback

I saw similar example in Stackoverflow and elsewhere, but it is not working for me. I use spring boot data jpa, junit5, h2 database and trying to make a simple acceptance test. Tests OK, but I was want that the changes in the database will be reverted after the test, but they are staying committed instead. I the tests I create a row in database and in other test I delete a row.
Here is the layers of my code:
The test:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)

public class ControllerAcceptanceTest {

@LocalServerPort
int randomServerPort;
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
private String url;

@BeforeEach
void setUp() {
    restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
}

@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback
void testCreate() throws Exception {
    url = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/api/wallet/create";
    UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
    PlayerDto playerDto = new PlayerDto();
    playerDto.setPlayerId(String.valueOf(uuid));
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, playerDto, Object.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
}

@Test
@Transactional
@Rollback
void testDelete() throws Exception {
    url = "http://localhost:" + randomServerPort + "/api/wallet/delete";
    WalletDto walletDto = new WalletDto();
    walletDto.setWalletId("1");
    ResponseEntity responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, walletDto, Object.class);
    assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, responseEntity.getStatusCode());
}
```

}

Controller:

```
@PostMapping (path = "/create", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void createWallet(@RequestBody PlayerDto playerDto) throws PlayerIdRedundantException {
    walletService.createWallet(playerDto.getPlayerId());
}
@PostMapping (path = "/delete", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public void deleteWallet(@RequestBody WalletDto walletDto) throws PlayerIdRedundantException {
    walletService.deleteWallet(walletDto.getWalletId());
}
```

Service:

```
@Transactional
public void createWallet(String playerId) throws PlayerIdRedundantException {
    checkPlayerId(playerId);
    Wallet wallet = Wallet.builder()
            .playerId(playerId)
            .balance(BigDecimal.valueOf(0))
            .build();
    walletRepository.save(wallet);
}
@Transactional
public void deleteWallet(String walletId) throws PlayerIdRedundantException {

    Wallet wallet = walletRepository.findById(Long.valueOf(walletId)).orElseThrow();
    walletRepository.delete(wallet);
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./src/main/resources/data/testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;OLD_INFORMATION_SCHEMA=TRUE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a common pitfall for transaction management when testing your Spring Boot application.

You have to differentiate between a test-managed and a spring-managed transaction. When using `@Transactional` on a method/class in your test, Spring Test will wrap the test execution within a transaction and will by default roll back any change to the database (so `@Rollback` is redundant).

This only applies to changes to the database that you directly make within this test-managed transaction, so if you would call `myRepository.save()` within the test method **directly**.

In your example, you're writing an acceptance test that *hits* your application from the outside with HTTP, like your clients/frontend would during production. This will trigger a Spring-managed transaction when your call reaches your service and commit the changes once the call finishes.

So you're actually having two transactions: the test-managed during your test execution and the Spring-managed *inside* your started application. From your test, you don't have access to the Spring-managed transaction and your rollback approach won't have a handle on this transaction inside the real application context.

To fix, you can, e.g., call `repository.deleteAll()` in a `BeforeEach` or `AfterEach.`

Also, consult the Javadoc of the `TransactionalTestExecutionListener` for a more detailed explanation.